# Filter with firebase recyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm using firebase recyclerview to get a list of users from the server. I would implement a search for other users, I've seen that I can use `orderByChild()` or `equalsTo()` to search.

This method works, but I have to write exactly the username I am looking for. You can do more in-depth research, for example by doing a search on a similar non-equal content.

This is a problem when I look for a username and I write a little. if this has the uppercase first I can not find it.
I hope someone helps me find a solution. Thank you

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendItem, FriendViewHolder>
    (FriendItem.class, R.layout.ranking_item, FriendViewHolder.class,
    mDatabase.child("user-profile").orderByChild("username").equalTo(search_edt.getText().toString())) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Database API does not support `regex` or `contains('<your-string>')` kind of support. You have to get all the data and filter on the client.

Comment: Ah ok thanks! So I have to use another type of filter! Thank you